# AzCopy Powershell tool - only one transfer is allowed with stream journal

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azcopy

I am trying to download multiple files from an Azure container using the following command:

```
& "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Azure\AzCopy\azcopy.exe" /Source:https://$accName.blob.core.windows.net/$cntrName /Dest:.  /SourceKey:$accKey /S /V /Y
```

I got an error

> "only one transfer is allowed with stream journal"

when execute it, anyone has explanation for this error and how to resolve it?

Comment: An update, I tried to change the container name and run the same command it worked fine. It seems to be a dead-lock on the old container name.

Answer (score 1):

Run into a similiar issue today. AzCopy keeps a journal file to be able to resume an incomplete operation. There seems to be an incomplete operation in the journal.

**Try to run the command without the /Y flag specified and resolve any prompts that appear**

For some reason the /Y flag, which is supposed to suppress all prompts can't handle the situation. https://learn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/azure/storage/common/storage-use-azcopy#journal-file-folder

More about journal files kept by AzCopy:

> Each time you issue a command to AzCopy, it checks whether a journal file exists in the default folder, or whether it exists in a folder that you specified via this option. If the journal file does not exist in either place, AzCopy treats the operation as new and generates a new journal file.
>
> If the journal file does exist, AzCopy checks whether the command line that you input matches the command line in the journal file. If the two command lines match, AzCopy resumes the incomplete operation. If they do not match, you are prompted to either overwrite the journal file to start a new operation, or to cancel the current operation.

From: https://learn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/azure/storage/common/storage-use-azcopy#journal-file-folder

Comment: Thanks for this informative reply. Unfortunately, removing the /Y flag is not possible in my scenario as I run this command from Azure DevOps release, therefore, prompts have to be managed automatically. What worked for me to avoid this issue is to create a unique container name with every release (using Release.ReleaseId environment variable), so I can assure that there is no racing conditions going on.